# Modifying arraylist after a creating iterator

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a List which is shared between two thread. In one thread I have created a iterator from the list object and in another thread i am modifying list. what can i do for avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: This is really basic stuff. Do you mind searching on the net first? Anyway, use a `List` that supports concurrency like [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) or use another structure that supports concurrent operations instead like a `Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a for loop. Like this it's not a problem even if the data structure is changed:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
  Integer n = list.get(i);
  // Anything inserted after the index i will be discovered in next iteration
}
```

To avoid performance issues be sure that your [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which has constant time access, while a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) has linear time access. Also remember to use [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) when accessing a list from multiple threads.

### Example

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    Integer n = list.get(i);
    System.out.println(n);
    if (n == 1) list.add(100);
}
```

*Output*

```
1
2
3
100
```

You can test it [here](http://rextester.com/YFME72033).

Comment: @alfasin: A for-each loop uses an iterator, but not a regular for loop with an index and `get`. It's still probably a semantic error, though; this needs proper synchronization.

Comment: @alfasin Oh really? It's such a pity that it works.. http://rextester.com/YFME72033

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList iterators like all java collections which are not from java.util.concurrent package throw concurrentModificationException when a structural change is detected while traversing the collection with an iterator.

If the list object needs to be shared between multiple threads, make sure you use appropriate external synchronisation or use a thread-safe class like CopyOnWriteArrayList.